# Unit testing Thread-Safety in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

Considering the following action:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> objectDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

source = () =>
{
    if (!objectDictionary.ContainsKey("demo"))
    { objectDictionary.Add("demo", "value"); }
};
```

This method is not thread-safe, because it's possible that 2 threads at the same time does enter the

```
public Dictionary<string, string> objectDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

condition.

Now I was thinking about a solution to test if this method is thread safe or not, so I've comed up with the following solution:

```
var isThreadSafe = true;

// Check to see if the action can be considered as thread safe.
try { for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { Parallel.Invoke(() => action(), () => action()); } }
catch (Exception) { isThreadSafe = false; }
```

The problem is that the bool 'isThreadSafe' is not set to fale. If I debug the application then I have an error according to thread-safety, 'An item with the same key has already been added'.

Now, is there another way to unit test this better?

Comment: is it not possible to use a concurrentdictionary instead of a normal one? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That's possible but this is just an example and the question does mean "How to test thread-safety".

Comment: the question is really why doesn't this catch the exception

Comment: True, do you have any idea? I tought by simulating it 1000 times, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Did you check which exceptions are catched? (it can be set via the menu of the visual studio that some exceptions cant be user catched if I remember correctly)

Comment: At the moment you're running only `2` tasks in parallel, probability of interference is less. Use `Paralell.For` so that you may run it parallel depending upon the resource availability of the machine. That should help I guess.

Comment: When I'm using a 'Parallel.For' with 1000000 simulatinious iterations, it doesn't work either, I guess I just have to give up :)

Comment: You might be interested in the Microsoft Research [CHESS project](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to clear the dictionary at the start of each iteration. Otherwise it doesn't matter that you are running this 100,000 times, 1000 times, or 1 time, there will only be one chance for the race to occur before the item is added and ContainsKey("demo") always returns false.

Solution is to clear the dictionary at the start of each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; n++)
{
    objectDictionary.Clear();
    Parallel.Invoke(action, action);
}
```

Be aware that Dictionary is not threadsafe and hammering any non-threadsafe class from multiple threads could just as easily result in a hang instead of an exception, although I suspect that in this case with Add and ContainsKey a hang won't occur.

Answer (score 3):

Testing code for race conditions is going to be *extremely* hard, particularly when it comes to automated tests.  The very definition of a race condition is that it's not going to be consistently reproducible.  On top of that, the problems that can result will vary widely.  It's possible for many different types of exceptions to be thrown, but it's also possible for garbage data to show up in your collection, for data to be dropped on the floor, or all sorts of other types of weird behavior.

Race conditions are also so very dependent on the timings of various operations.  When you debug the program and step through it you end up artificially (and often dramatically) changing those timings in ways that can change the results of various race conditions.  The very act of debugging the program can either create, or hide, different bugs, which you appear to be seeing right now.

To accurately test all of the possible erroneous behaviors you'd need to have predicted what could go wrong in the first place, which means understanding all of the possible unsupported behaviors.  This is why dealing with multithreaded programs is so hard.

Comment: Thanks for this. I do understand that this is hard to test, but I would like to cover as much as possible scenario's.

Comment: @Complexity To actually comprehensively test a significant percentage of the possible execution paths is effectively impossible.  It's hard enough with single threaded code to cover a noticeable percentage of possible permutations of execution in a complex program, but when you have multiple threads and the ordering of every single operation is a possible location of variance, really having a good chance of finding bugs you didn't expect is very, very low.  Realistically you need to simply be able to write programs that you can reason about effectively.